# How to load an url from recyclerview newsapi

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Im working on a news reader app that uses fragments. I get my data from the newsapi. So far I have managed to pull the data from the api and display it in a recyclerview but when I click on an item, nothing happens!

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String API_KEY= "c03ceb6a99b14050875f56xxxxxxxx";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);

        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(articles,getActivity());
        recyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(HomeFragment.this);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        LoadJsonData();
        return rootView;


    }

    public void LoadJsonData(){

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        String country = Utils.getCountry();

        Call <News> call;
        call = apiInterface.getNews(country,API_KEY);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<News>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<News> call, Response<News> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().getArticle() != null){

                    if (!articles.isEmpty()){
                        articles.clear();
                    }

                    articles = response.body().getArticle();
                    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(articles,getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
                    recyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(HomeFragment.this);
                    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No result",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<News> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

      articles.get(position);


    }


}
```

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Article> articles;
    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(int position);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Article> articles, Context context) {
        this.articles = articles;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate((R.layout.card_view_layout), viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        final ViewHolder holder = viewHolder;
        Article model = articles.get(i);

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions.placeholder(Utils.getRandomDrawbleColor());
        requestOptions.error(Utils.getRandomDrawbleColor());
        requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL);
        requestOptions.centerCrop();

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(model.getUrlToImage())
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.title.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.desc.setText(model.getDescription());
        holder.source.setText(model.getSource().getName());
        holder.time.setText(" \u2022 " + Utils.DateToTimeFormat(model.getPublishedAt()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return articles.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        TextView title, desc, source, time;
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            source = itemView.findViewById(R.id.source);
            time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headline_image);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_load);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (onItemClickListener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            onItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }


                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems all you are doing inside your onClick is getting the item position. It is now up to you to do something with that position.

So the question comes down to, what do you want to do?

Launch a details activity/fragment to display more info? That is a typical pattern for mobile.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,DetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra(Your Data);
startActivity(i);
```